# Python grocery list program not displaying bag type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm scratching my head over this one. I can't figure out why my program is not displaying the bag type after providing "paper" or "plastic" during the "Please choose paper or plastic" in `get_paper_or_plastic` function. Here's my code:

```
maximum_number_of_groceries = 500

def get_string(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    return value

def valid_real(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def get_real(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    while not valid_real(value):
        print(value, "is not a number. Please provide a number.")
        value = input(prompt)
    return float(value)


def get_paper_or_plastic(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    if value == "plastic" or value == "Plastic" or value == "paper" or value == "Paper":
        return value
    else:
        print("That is not a valid bag type. Please choose paper or plastic")
        value = input(prompt)

def y_or_n(prompt):
    value = ""

    value = input(prompt)
    while True:
        if value == "Y" or value == "y":
            return False
        elif value == "N" or value == "n":
            return True
        else:
            print("Not a valid input. Please type Y or N")
            value = input(prompt)

def get_groceries(grocery_name, quantity,paper_or_plastic):
    done = False
    counter = 0
    while not done:
        grocery_name[counter] = get_string("What grocery do you need today? ")
        quantity[counter] = get_real("How much of that item do you need today?")
        counter = counter + 1
        done = y_or_n("Do you need anymore groceries (Y/N)?")
    paper_or_plastic = get_paper_or_plastic("Do you want your groceries bagged in paper or plastic bags today?")
    return counter

def calculate_total_groceries(quantity):
    counter = 0
    total_quantity = 0

    while counter < len(quantity):
        total_quantity = total_quantity + int(quantity[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
    return total_quantity

def grocery_list():
    grocery_name = ["" for x in range (maximum_number_of_groceries)]
    quantity = [0.0 for x in range (maximum_number_of_groceries)]
    total_quantity = 0
    paper_or_plastic = ""
    get_groceries(grocery_name, quantity, paper_or_plastic)
    total_quantity = calculate_total_groceries(quantity)


    print ("Total number of groceries purchased is: ", total_quantity," and you have chosen a bag type of ", paper_or_plastic)

grocery_list()
```

Comment: the `value == "plastic" or ...` part can be majorly improved by just changing it to `value.lower() in ("paper", "plastic")`. Basically the same for all of your yes-no code. Not sure why value is being initialized to an empty string either.

Comment: Are strings not immutable even in pass by reference in python? You only return a counter from the groceries, and you never print the actual choice of bag in your bagmethod.

Comment: ohhh you're trying to pass by reference... Python doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

If by "display", you mean "print", then the reason your program is not printing the bag type is quite simple: you have no instance of the print function being called with the bag type as a parameter. Returning something doesn't cause it to be printed.

BTW, `value == "plastic" or value == "Plastic" or value == "paper" or value == "Paper"` can be replaced by `value.lower() in ['plastic','paper']`

Comment: Use a tuple instead of list.

Comment: @MustacheMoses What is the advantage of a tuple?